# GCC implicit alignment problem. (64-bit code)

Tags: c, gcc, memory-alignment

How can I explicitly disable alignment on defined variable in gcc?
Take this code:

```
typedef struct{
  unsigned long long offset;
  unsigned long long size;
  unsigned long type;
  unsigned long acpi;
}memstruct;

memstruct *memstrx;
```

This would define an structure having a size of 24 bytes.
I tried doing:

```
memstrx=(void*)(0x502);
```

So
`&memstrx[0]` should have an value of 0x502
`&memstrx[1]` , 0x51A
`&memstrx[2]` , 0x532
... and so on and so forth.

But things doesn't seem to be right.

Instead, the
`&memstrx[1]` , displays an address of 0x522
`&memstrx[2]` , 0x542
`&memstrx[3]` , 0x552

... and so on and so forth.

I suspect GCC has implicitly re-sized the structure to 32 bytes (from 24 bytes), forcing a (64-bit alignment  of each entry). And I don't really want this behavior only for this structure. How should I tell GCC to not align that structure?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No it can't be done.

The minimal size of the structure you show is 8*4 = 32 bytes.

sizeof(unsigned long) = 8 on 64 bit architecture (Linux)

**Edit:** if you would use

-`unsigned` instead of `unsigned long`

or

- `uint32_t` and `uint64_t` instead of `unsigned long` and `unsigned long long`

you would get expected alignment.

Comment: what do you mean by "No it isn't its minimal size is 8*4 = 32 bytes.", size of a structure?

Comment: Artyom means `unsigned long` is 8 bytes on a 64-bit machine. Use plain `unsigned` if you want 32 bits, or better yet use exact-size types (`uint32_t` and `uint64_t`) rather than types that could vary in size.

Answer (score 2):

#pragma pack(x) can change the structure alignment restrictions on both GCC and MSVC.

GCC uses the LP64 model for 64bit builds - which means longs and pointers are 64bits. You need to change to unsigned int for your 32bit fields, OR use  and uint32_t and uint64_t for stable field sizes.

```
#pragma pack(1)

typedef struct{
  unsigned long long offset;
  unsigned long long size;
  unsigned int type;
  unsigned int acpi;
}memstruct;

#pragma pack()
```

Answer (score 1):

here's one option to control alignment using gcc:

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Structure_002dPacking-Pragmas.html

Comment: It has nothing to do with alignment - he just misses correct types

Comment: @Artyom that issue had been addressed in another answer (your post) at the time i posted. however, the information i posted had not been provided in any responses at the time i posted. each answer will be useful, depending on the reader/context. cheers